# What should i do to remove a value from min heap when the left and right child are equal and smaller than their parent

Tags: c, heap, min

What should i do to remove a value from min heap when the left and right child are equal and smaller than their parent. For example i have a value 0 on the root of my min heap and want to remove it. I'll swap 0 with the last element of my vector(value=12), after that, i need to run the function that turns the vector into a min-heap again(min-heapfy), but in my example i exchanged 0 with 12, and now 12 is on the root and 0 will be soon returned. I have to swap 12 with the left child(1) or right child(1), how can i know which of this number 1 entered in the vector first?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int left(int i){
    return 2*i;
}

int right(int i){
    return 2*i +1;
}

void swap_pos(int *vi, int *vm){
    int aux;
    aux = *vi;
    *vi = *vm;
    *vm = aux;
}

void heapify(int *v, int i,int heap_size){ 
    int l,r,menor_ind = i;
    l = left(i); 
    r = right(i); 
    if(l<=heap_size && v[l]<v[i]) menor_ind = l;
    if(r<=heap_size && v[r]<v[menor_ind]) menor_ind = r;
    if(menor_ind!= i){
        swap_pos(&v[i],&v[menor_ind]);
        heapify(v,menor_ind,heap_size);
    }
}

void build_min_heap(int v[],int heap_size){
    int i;
    for(i=heap_size/2; i>=1; i--){
        heapify(v,i,heap_size);
    }
}

int extract(int *v, int *heap_size){
    int ret = v[1];
    if(*heap_size==0) return -1;// erro
    swap_pos(&v[*heap_size],&v[1]); // swap root with the last element
    (*heap_size)--;
    heapify(v,1,*heap_size);
    return ret;
}

void heap_sort(int *v, int *heap_size){
    while(*heap_size>=2){
        swap_pos(&v[1],&v[*heap_size]);
        (*heap_size)--;
        heapify(v,1,*heap_size);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int heap_size = 9;
    int i, v[] = {-1,6,12,3,1,5,0,1,9,7};
    build_min_heap(v,heap_size);
    printf("%d\n",extract(v,&heap_size));
    //heap_sort(v,&heap_size);
    for(i=1; i<=heap_size; i++){
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the heap goes, `1` and `1` are equal. (Indeed, that is generally true.) So it doesn't matter which `1` becomes the new root. The `12` will percolate up the heap until it finds some place to rest, possibly at the fringe but not necessarily. There's nothing which requires it to get back to where it came from, and it's very likely that it won't.

Why do you think the code you present isn't correct?

Comment: It's because my min-heap represents a queue of pacients from an hospital and 1 are their priority, if they arrive with the same priority i need to remove from heap who arrived first. so in this case it will matter who will be removed, i think i'll need to create another if condition to verify who arrived first

Comment: @RoniCésardeCastro: In that case, `1` is not their priority. It's *part of* their priority. The rest of their priority is their arrival time. You need to use both parts of the priority as the heap value. In C++ this would be *much* easier (and it already has priority queues in the standard library), but it's only a little painful in C: just use a struct containing both values.